# Using WHERE, CASE, AND, LIKE together in the same SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, looker

I'm having trouble coming up with the right query that does the following: Let's say we somehow take input from user for the value of two columns, `datestamp` and `brand` (what happens is a [Looker](http://looker.com/guide/getting-started) UI feeds this to the query). For simplicity let's say our schema includes both columns and I only want to get them back, so:

```
SELECT brand, datestamp
FROM my_table
WHERE
```

I'm not sure how I should write the rest. Here's what's desired:

- The user be able to type `yesterday`, `today`, `last x days` for some `x` or a string like `20181001` and the right date gets passed to the query.
- The user be able to specify what `brand` should be equal to and that gets passed to the query.

  ```
  ( CASE
      WHEN position(' TO ' IN UPPER({% parameter filter_datestamp %})) > 0 THEN
              datestamp >= SUBSTR({% parameter filter_datestamp %}, 0, strpos(UPPER({% parameter filter_datestamp %}), ' TO ') - 1) AND
              datestamp <= SUBSTR({% parameter filter_datestamp %}, strpos(UPPER({% parameter filter_datestamp %}), ' TO ')  + 4)
              AND
              brand LIKE {% parameter filter_brand %}

      WHEN filter_datestamp = 'today' THEN datestamp = date_format(CURRENT_DATE,'yyyyMMdd')
      AND brand LIKE {% parameter filter_brand %}


      WHEN datestamp = 'yesterday' THEN datestamp = date_format(DATE_ADD('day', -1, CURRENT_DATE),'%Y%m%d')
      AND brand LIKE {% parameter filter_brand %}

      WHEN datestamp LIKE 'last % days' THEN datestamp >= date_format(DATE_ADD('day', -CAST(split({% parameter filter_datestamp %}, ' ')[2] AS INT), CURRENT_DATE),'%Y%m%d')
      AND brand LIKE {% parameter filter_brand %}

      ELSE datestamp LIKE {% parameter filter_datestamp %}
      AND brand LIKE {% parameter filter_brand %}

    END )
  ```

If the query works, the result should be a number of rows with `brand` and `datestamp` equal to what the user wants. All rows will be identical (I actually want something else but think I can do that if the `CASE` is resolved).

Please write the complete query for me. I'm not sure where `WHERE` goes with respect to `CASE`, `WHEN`, `AND`, and other keywords present in this case.

Comment: Who is calling MySQL in this case?  I don't think it should be the job of MySQL to convert `yesterday` into a date, and in fact dates by themselves is the only thing your query ought to really be accepting as input parameters.  So, your app language (e.g. PHP, Java, etc.) should probably be involved here.

Comment: I guess Tim is right. That's not what SQL is made for. Can it do it? Probably. But the performance will be crappy...

Comment: It is much easier do this logic in the app (Java, C#, Visual Basic). Then pass a `from_date` and `to_date` parameter to the query and simply test `WHERE theDate >= ? AND theDate < ?`. Make sure that the second parameter `to_date` is the next day. This makes it easier to include dates having times up close to midnight. `theDate` column should have a date type, not a text type.

Comment: For those wondering, the "`yesterday, today, last x days for some x or a string like 20181001`" bit is a reference to looker's filter expressions, which allow for that kind of statement to be translated into a SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Looker, I think this can all be done fairly simply just by using [templated filters](https://docs.looker.com/data-modeling/learning-lookml/templated-filters) instead of parameters like you have now.

Basically, templated filters automatically apply the condition chosen to the query, so instead of having to explicitly account for all the possible forms of user input with the CASE statements you currently have, you could just have

```
{% condition filter_datestamp %} datestamp {% endcondition %}
```

That one line can replace all of the datestamp case statements-- You can include the brand filter as well by adding it on to the end like:

```
 {% condition filter_datestamp %} datestamp {% endcondition %} 
 AND brand LIKE {% parameter filter_brand %}
```

That should write the SQL desired! If you input "foo" for filter_brand and "yesterday" for filter_datestamp, it will write:

```
SELECT brand, datestamp
FROM my_table
WHERE ((( datestamp ) >= ((DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 day))) AND ( datestamp ) < ((DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -1 day),INTERVAL 1 day)))))
 AND brand LIKE 'foo'
```

The full LookML to have that as a derived table (what I guessed you were trying to do) looks like

```
view: test {
  derived_table: {
    sql:
    SELECT brand, datestamp
    FROM my_table
    WHERE {% condition filter_datestamp %} datestamp {% endcondition %}
     AND brand LIKE {% parameter filter_brand %};;
  }


  filter: filter_datestamp {
    type: date
  }

  filter: filter_brand {
    type: string
  }

  dimension: brand {
    type: string
    sql: ${TABLE}.brand ;;
  }
  dimension: datestamp {
    type: date
    sql: ${TABLE}.datestamp ;;
  }
}
```

Let me know if that scans or if there's anything that doesn't make sense about that! Also, in the future I'd invite you to come post on our Community Forums at [discourse.looker.com](http://discourse.looker.com) :) We've got lots of Looker Experts there who'd love to answer stuff like this.

Answer (score -1):

This could be your Query:

```
SELECT brand, datestamp   FROM my_table
 WHERE (DATE (datestamp) = DATE (NOW ())
     OR DATE (datestamp) >= DATE_SUB (DATE (NOW ()), INTERVAL 'x' DAY) DATE(NOW()))
       AND brand = '<>';
```

but for this u will have to pas x every time.
for today pass 0
for yesterday pass 1
for last 'x' pass that 'x'